# Unable to pass large amount of data cross domain

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-domain

I'm using wcf service in my c# mvc application. I need to get through wcf to the client side (to the controller) a large amount of data (approximately 20000 records).

In the local version - I get all the records very well, but in the server version I don't get anything if I don't limit the query to 1000 records.

When it's not limited and trying to bring all the records, this is what I get in client log:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to xxx/WCF.svc. This could be due
>   to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I've added this to web.config in client but it didn't help:

```
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the WCF tracing on the server side show any errors?

Comment: Why don't you just use paging and request say 1000 items at a time?  Fetching everything at once is arguably a bad design choice. Is this going over the Internet or just a corporate LAN? You can still use tcp for cross-domain. If its a LAN you should be using **tcpBinding**.  J. Lowy, "Programming WCF Services", 3rd Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your binding configuration set to allow large data? 
If you are using an httpbinding you should configure your endpoint and your service in this way

```
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="LargeDataBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="998192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Other then that try to increase on your server the maximum length of content in a request supported by the IIS

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Though this is a fine answer, it encourages bad practices by _hiding the symptom and not fixing the cause_ - in this case the OP's poor design of fetching everything at once rather than using paging.

Answer (score 1):

As Mackho said, this you should increase the timeouts in the first configuration settings. Also, the clients must increase their timeout values and the maximum content that they can get from the server.

Additional, you can use streaming for your service if you really need to pass all the data and don't want to use paging. To configure your service to run in stream mode, add:

```
<bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding transferMode="Streamed" name="LargeDataBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="998192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Note that your client settings are also important:

- The lowest timeouts will prevail (from the client or the server)
- The lowest between maxStringContentLength and the settings from the client about how much they can receive will prevail
- To use streaming, the client must support it and have the same setting too (otherwise, on the client the data will be buffered)

It really depends if the exception is thrown by the server or by the client. Enable WCF tracing in both of them and see where the exception is thrown, then do the necessary configurations on that side.